# Prevent design system library from being bundled (creating chunks) with main application

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I have a React app which is using few NPM packages, and one of them being my design system lib. Building the bundle with Webpack.
The design system library is a pretty large library and I'd like to load it as a separate `<script>` tag on the page instead of as one of the chunks (so that I can do additional caching optimizations specifically for this library).

Is there any way to tell Webpack config to exclude the library from build (exclude it from chunks)? And if so, how would I reference the library in code. Would I need to change anything in terms of imports?

The app code is importing code with ESM, something along these lines:

```
import { Box } from 'my-design-system';

// react component functions here
```